# error in console moved permanently

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx

I have a Magento Installation version 1.9.3.1.
Until yesterday It was working fine, but now the frontpage is not working with the error - Too many redirects.

On further checking in the console(firebug), I can see all the files are showing as moved permanently
as also
it is adding a extra slash / that is two slash in the end of the sitename in the browser address.
also in console all the get pages are showing as //

**update:**

I observed that it is only home-page/index.php where I am facing this issue.
for example If I am accessing site/category-name
it is working fine.

How I can fix that.

Comment: Can you access the admin?

Comment: Yes I am able to access the admin, without any issue.

Comment: Please check core_config_data table and verify **`web/unsecure/base_url`** and **`web/secure/base_url`** is setup properly.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora - I checked that, didn't see any problem there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please look into `core_config_data` table and make sure
   `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` is setup properly.
2. Please check with the recent changes in `.htaccess` file if you are
   using Apache

Comment: No it is nginx. so  `.htaccess` shouldn't have any effect?